# AWS Device Farm iPhone SE Password field not showing cursor and '•'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, aws-device-farm

I am using AWS device farm for testing purpose.
There is password Text field in 1 view controller.
In iPhone SE when I click and type on Password field, It shows nothing(not even cursor) but when I click on login Code is able to take password from field.

It does not happen with iPhone 11. iPhone 11 shows  '•' (black dot) and cursor.
I am not able to reproduce this on iPhone SE simulator.

Edit:
Both iPhone SE and iPhone 11 has iOS 13.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

We need some more info before getting an answer, what IOS versions are the SE and 11? if that's different, that might be your issue.

Comment: SE and 11 both has iOS 13 version.

Comment: Try IOS 14 on both devices. if its still there, then it's probably in the code.